# Как создать текстовый канал и отправить туда сообщение?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Мне нужно отправить embed в канал, который я создал с помощью бота, но я не могу это реализовать.
Ниже как я пробовал его создать и отправить

```js
let text = interaction.guild.channels.create(`classic ${interaction.username}`, {
                type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
                parent: '943522879901937728',
                permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone.id,
                    deny:['SEND_MESSAGES'],
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                },
            ],
            });
            const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('primary')
                    .setLabel('1')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
            );
            const clas = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Управление столом`)
            .setDescription(`
            Нажмите на кнопку, чтобы управлять действиями на столе.
            Первые 10 цифр - убийство игроков.
            Последние 10 цифр - фолы.
            `)
        const hert = await text.send({embeds:[clas], components:[row]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вы уж больно много всего нагородили.
Так можно

```js
let ParentCanalId = "X6482647102075701Y"; //Id канала, внутри которого будет новый канал
client.channels.fetch(ParentCanalId) //Получаем родительский канал
  .then(parentchannel => {
    parentchannel.createChannel("test", 
    {/*Тут дополнительные опции создвния канала, если нужно*/}
    )
      .then(channel => {
        const embed = {
          title: `Управление столом`,
          description: `
    Нажмите на кнопку, чтобы управлять действиями на столе.
    Первые 10 цифр - убийство игроков.
    Последние 10 цифр - фолы.`
        };
        channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
      })
  })
```